# Proving that $f$ is integrable if limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

First of all please keep in mind that i want a hint not a full solution. Let $P$ be partition on $[a,b]$. Let $h(P)=\max_{i\leq j \leq n}|x_j - x_{j-1}|$. Let $c$ = $(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n)$ such that $c_j \in [x_{j-1}, x_j]$. Let $k(f,P,c) = \sum_1^n (f_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})$. We say that $J=\lim_{h(P)\to 0}k(f,P,c)$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ exsit $\delta > 0$, so that for everery partition points $c_j$ i,e, (P,c) whose paramater $h(P) < \delta$, it is true that $|J - k(f,P,c)| < \epsilon$. Also let $s(f,P) \leq k(f,P,c) \leq S(f,P)$ and $s(f,P) = \inf_ck(f,P,c)$ and $S(f,P) = \sup_ck(f,P,c)$

Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable  iff  $\lim_{h(P)\to 0}k(f,P,c)$ exists.

So lets assume that $f$ is integrable. Then it follows that lower and upper integrals are equal and that lower integral($L$) is equal to $\sup_ps(f,P)$ and upper is eqaul to $\inf_pS(f,P)$. When $h(P)\to 0$ then  number of partition points in $P$ tends to infinity, because only way to get $h(P)$ closer to $0$ is to add more partition points to $P$. I am going to write that down as $P\to \infty$.

We have then $s(f,P) \leq k(f,P,c) \leq S(f,P)$ Now i am going to let $\lim_{P\to \infty}$ which is equal to $\lim_{h(P)\to 0}$.

Now let $\lim_{P\to \infty}(s(f,P) \leq k(f,P,c) \leq S(f,P))$.

Now $\lim_{P\to \infty}s(f,P) = \sup_ps(f,P)$ , because when we add more and more points ot refinment $P$, $s(f,P)$ is getting closer and closer to $\sup_ps(f,P)$ i.e. $\sup_ps(f,P)$ is its limit. So $\lim_{P\to \infty}s(f,P) = \sup_ps(f,P) = L$.

Now $\lim_{P\to \infty}S(f,P) = \inf_pS(f,P)$ , because when we add more and more points ot refinment $P$, $S(f,P)$ is getting closer and closer to $\inf_pS(f,P)$ i.e. $\inf_pS(f,P)$ is its limit. So $\lim_{P\to \infty}S(f,P) = \inf_pS(f,P) = U$.

We also know that if $f$ is integrable $U=L$. By sandwich therem i have that $k(f,P,c)=U=L$. Which means that $\lim_{h(P)\to 0}k(f,P,c)$ exists.

Is this prof correct and how do I go about proving implication in other direction?

Comment: Oh, my: spacing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This direction looks good to me.

Hint for the other direction, if you wish to prove that
$$\sup_P s(f,P) = \inf_P S(f,P),$$
it suffices to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P^*$ such that 
$S(f,P^*) - s(f,P^*) < \epsilon$.

And you know that $\lim_{|P|\rightarrow 0} k(f,P,c) = L$. Now for each $\epsilon >0$, there exists a partition $P$ with $|P|<r$ such that 
$$L-\frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq k(f,P,c) \leq L-\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
The above inequality will hold for each tagged point $c$ in the partition, you can choose $c$ such that $k(f,P,c)$ is close to $s(f,P)$ or close to $S(f,P)$.